# JavaFx rotate button when hover mouse

Tags: javafx

is there is any way to **rotate** the Button when i put the mouse on it (**hover**) ?
by using pure **JavaFx** , or by using **CSS** Styling ?
if not , i look for any simple animation when hover on mouse

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create a `RotateTransition` and use mouse handlers to start and pause it:

```
Button button = ... ;

RotateTransition rotation = new RotateTransition(Duration.seconds(0.5), button);
rotation.setCycleCount(Animation.INDEFINITE);
rotation.setByAngle(360);

button.setOnMouseEntered(e -> rotation.play());
button.setOnMouseExited(e -> rotation.pause());
```

Comment: ohhh , great maan , thanks a lot ♥ , but can i make it just one rotation ?

Comment: Yes, just set the cycle count to 1

Comment: Thank you very much bro. You save my life.